# how to maintain the checked state of dynamically generated radio buttons while using pagination in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how to maintain the checked state of dynamically generated radio buttons while using pagination in php?
am using this code for online quiz application,while i move to next page the radio button selected value or post or automatically submit.so i got the error like offset errors.
i need to keep my selected radio buttons to next or previous page.sorry for my bad english.
please help any one.thanks in advance

```
include('connection.php');
mysql_select_db('quiz_apptitude');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age");

$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else { 
    $pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 2; 

$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

if ($pn < 1) {
    $pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
    $pn = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age $limit"); 

$i=0;
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 

   $Question[]=$row['prob_Question'];
$optA[]=$row['prob_OptionA'];
$optB[]=$row['prob_OptionB'];
$optC[]=$row['prob_OptionC'];
$optD[]=$row['prob_OptionD'];
$ans[]=$row['prob_Answer'];
$Qid[]=$row['prob_Qid'];


                     $r=$i+1;

    $outputList .= '<table><tr>
              <td> '.$r.' . '.$Question[$i].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$Qid[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>

              <td><input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"   value="'.$optA[$i].'"/>
                '.$optA[$i].'</td></tr>
                <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optB[$i].'" />
                '.$optB[$i].'</td></tr>
             <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"   value="'.$optC[$i].'"  />
               '.$optC[$i].'</td></tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"   value="'.$optD[$i].'"  />
            '.$optD[$i].'</td></tr>

            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$ans[$i].'"  value="'.$ans[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr></table>';

$i++;

}
$count=count($Qid);

$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){

    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    } 

    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    } 
}


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>online QiuZ</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.pagNumActive {
    color: #000;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#060 1px solid; background-color: #D2FFD2; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
.paginationNumbers a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:#999 1px solid; background-color:#F0F0F0; padding-left:3px; padding-right:3px;
}
-->
</style>



</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
     <h2>Problem On Age</h2>
   </div> 
   <!--   <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php //echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>-->
      <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
      <form name="prob_age" id="prob_age" method="post" action="result-age.php" >
      <?php print "$outputList"; ?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

      </form>

      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to use AJAX to save automatically when you check a radio button. When you change page, your page refresh, so your variable can't be conserved, or maybe by put datas in SESSION...

Comment: I agree with @Raphaël. Otherwise consider only fetching the pieces of your html that are not related to the checkboxes. I.e. NOT replace the checkboxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to keep selected radio button values to next page in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180601/how-to-keep-selected-radio-button-values-to-next-page-in-php)