# how to keep selected radio button values to next page in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am doing an online quiz application, i need to keep all selected radio button values  to next page when i click the next button,becoz am using pagination.In this following code when am moving to next page it shows undefined offset errors .I got one more syntax error like unexpected checked in this line />'.$optA[$i].'
i need solution for these problems please help anyone,thanks in advance

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    mysql_select_db('quiz_apptitude');
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age");
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
    if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
        $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
    } else { 
        $pn = 1;
    } 

    $itemsPerPage = 2; 

    $lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

    if ($pn < 1) {
        $pn = 1; 
    } else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
        $pn = $lastPage; 
    } 

    $centerPages = "";
    $sub1 = $pn - 1;
    $sub2 = $pn - 2;
    $add1 = $pn + 1;
    $add2 = $pn + 2;
    if ($pn == 1) {
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    } else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    } else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    } else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
        $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    }

    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age $limit") or die('error'); 
    //$total=mysql_num_rows($sql2) ;
    $i=0;
    $outputList = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 

       $Question[]=$row['prob_Question'];
    $optA[]=$row['prob_OptionA'];
    $optB[]=$row['prob_OptionB'];
    $optC[]=$row['prob_OptionC'];
    $optD[]=$row['prob_OptionD'];
    $ans[]=$row['prob_Answer'];
    $Qid[$i]=$row['prob_Qid'];

        $ans[$i]=$row['prob_Answer'];
                         $r=$i+1;




        $outputList .= '<table><tr>
                  <td> '.$r.' . '.$Question[$i].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$Qid[$i].'" /></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>

                  <td><input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optA[$i].'" <?php echo '.$optA[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> 
                    '.$optA[$i].'</td></tr>
                    <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optB[$i].'" <?php echo '.$optB[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                    '.$optB[$i].'</td></tr>
                 <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"  id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optC[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optC[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
                   '.$optC[$i].'</td></tr>
                <tr>  <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optD[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optD[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
                '.$optD[$i].'</td></tr>

                <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$ans[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$ans[$i].'" /></td>
                </tr></table>';

    $i++;
    }

    $count=count($Qid);
    $paginationDisplay = ""; 
    if ($lastPage != "1"){

        $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

        if ($pn != 1) {
            $previous = $pn - 1;

            $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
        } 

        $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

        if ($pn != $lastPage) {
            $nextPage = $pn + 1;

            $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '">Next</a> ';
        } 
    }

    ?>

<?php
session_start();


include('connection.php');
mysql_select_db('quiz_apptitude');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age");
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else { 
    $pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 2; 

$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

if ($pn < 1) {
    $pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
    $pn = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prob_on_age $limit") or die('error'); 
//$total=mysql_num_rows($sql2) ;
$i=0;
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 

   $Question[]=$row['prob_Question'];
$optA[]=$row['prob_OptionA'];
$optB[]=$row['prob_OptionB'];
$optC[]=$row['prob_OptionC'];
$optD[]=$row['prob_OptionD'];
$ans[]=$row['prob_Answer'];
$Qid[$i]=$row['prob_Qid'];

    $ans[$i]=$row['prob_Answer'];
                     $r=$i+1;




    $outputList .= '<table><tr>
              <td> '.$r.' . '.$Question[$i].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$Qid[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>

              <td><input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optA[$i].'" <?php echo '.$optA[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> 
                '.$optA[$i].'</td></tr>
                <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optB[$i].'" <?php echo '.$optB[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                '.$optB[$i].'</td></tr>
             <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"  id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optC[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optC[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
               '.$optC[$i].'</td></tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optD[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optD[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
            '.$optD[$i].'</td></tr>

            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$ans[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$ans[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr></table>';

$i++;


}

$count=count($Qid);








$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){

    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    } 

    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;

        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '">Next</a> ';
    } 
}

?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>online QiuZ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
         <h2>Problem On Age</h2>
       </div> 
       <!--   <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php //echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>-->
          <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
          <form name="prob_age" id="prob_age" method="post" action="result-age.php" >
          <?php print "$outputList"; ?>

          <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

          </form>
          </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `cookie` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

As I have check the code, I found that your variable $output list data is not correct. replace that by following:

You are echoing in the string of the php variable with the if condition:

```
<?php echo '.$optB[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
```

The above line you are using in the $output variable that is not correct. You need to change this line as following:

```
$output .= ....//other code
$output .= ($optB[$i] == $_POST[$Qid[$i]]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
$output .= ......
```

Replace your each `<?php echo` in the string of `$output` variable as above.

**EDITED:**

Check you below code:

```
$outputList .='<table><tr>
              <td> '.$r.' . '.$Question[$i].'</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$Qid[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>

              <td><input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optA[$i].'" 

<?php echo '.$optA[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
```

> //here you are starting the php tag again in within php tag. so remove
>   the php and 
>       echo tags. and use as i have mention
>   use this as $outputList .= ($optA[$i] == $_POST[$Qid[$i]]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
>   and close the above sting before it. and do it similarly for other.

```
/> 
                '.$optA[$i].'</td></tr>
                <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optB[$i].'" <?php echo '.$optB[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                '.$optB[$i].'</td></tr>
             <tr> <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'"  id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optC[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optC[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
               '.$optC[$i].'</td></tr>
            <tr>  <td><input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optD[$i].'"  <?php echo '.$optD[$i].' == $_POST[''.$Qid[$i].''] ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
            '.$optD[$i].'</td></tr>

            <tr>  <td><input type="hidden" name="'.$ans[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$ans[$i].'" /></td>
            </tr></table>';
```

> Note: if you are not getting what I am saying then let me know I will
>   post modified code. and will modify more you.

Comment: Heart: sorry... i could not get you,please explain briefly

Comment: <input type="radio"  name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'"  value="'.$optA[$i].'" $output .= ($optA[$i] == $_POST[$Qid[$i]]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';/> 
                '.$optA[$i].' i edited like above,again i got syntax error undefined checked.agin if am wrong please explain again

Comment: @user1877928 not that use it. `<input type="radio" name=" '.$Qid[$i].'" id="'.$Qid[$i].'" value="'.$optA[$i].'"';` //here close the string then `$output .= ($optA[$i] == $_POST[$Qid[$i]]) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';` //then again close the string `$output .= '/> '.$optA[$i].'...`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it with `PHP Sessions` and/or `Cookies` (almost the same for your case) but if for any reason something goes wrong in the middle of the quiz... you will lose all the progress and the user have to start all over again.

If the quiz is short, you can do it that way, but if it's >= middle or even long one... I will suggest to use `$_POST` & `Forms` instead of pagination links. and of course, save the progress in the meanwhile.

With this, if you want to pre-check radio buttons, input field, or anything... just have to call the proper variable next time you open that page (could be also another day because the values are storage in your server and not in user machine.)
good luck

Comment: sorry i could not get you,am going to use 20 questions per each page

Comment: Using session or cookies you depend on the user computer to give him the oportunity to continue an already started quiz. If you use `Form & post` and save the data in each page, The user is able to continue at any time on any computer. Of course you can preload the info including your radio buttons with `PHP var`.

Comment: i could not get you please explain briefly

Comment: what you do not understand? The `PHP` code you wrote above is yours or is copied from somewhere?